# jQuery adding with ++ multiplies after using function again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a function called test (for example), and it works like this:

```
function test(){
    var i = 0;

    $('.container').click(function(){
        $(this).append('<div class="element"></div>');
        $('.element').click(function(){
            if (i >= 10){
                $('this').remove();
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        });
    });
};
test();
```

When I click the class `.container`, a div appends with the classname `.element`. When I click this div, var `i` goes up, until reaching 10. Then the div called `.element` is removed.

The problem is, is when I click `.container` again, after `.element` is removed, the `i` variable is acting like its clicked twice. After that trice, and so on. How do I counteract this?

Comment: your code showing $('element') instead of $('.element')

Comment: Oh whoops. It's an example, but it should look good anyway :p

Comment: If you can share your jsfiddle, that will be great

Comment: Well, I am making this for a company I am doing an internship at. I think I am not allowed to share the actual code

Comment: Do not embed click handlers. That's bound to end in trouble.

Comment: Another correction: $('this').remove();  should be $(this).remove();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach event to dynamically added elements using `.on()`

```
$('.container').click(function(){
        $(this).append('<div class="element"></div>');

    });

 $('body').on('click','.element',function(){
   if (i >= 10){
      $(this).remove();
   } else {
         i++;
   }
});
```

Also remove .element div event handler inside .container div

Comment: `i` isn't defined :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly! I will mark the answer as 'accepted' once the time limit is over

Comment: I understand, but `var i=0` is the only line that is missing.

Comment: @LinkinTED added :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to bind an element like this

You can also use on / bind method to attached an event to dynamic elements.

```
$(document).on('click','.element',function(){
   if (i >= 10){
      $(this).remove();
   } else {
      i++;
   }
});
```

**OR**

```
$(document).bind('click','.element',function(){
       if (i >= 10){
          $(this).remove();
       } else {
          i++;
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `click` event for `.element` like below.

```js
var i = 0;

function test() {
  $('.container').click(function() {
    $(this).append('<div class="element"></div>');
  });
};
test();

$('body').on('click', '.element', function() {
  if (i >= 10) {
    $('this').remove();
  } else {
    i++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  Click Me!
</div>
```